# Links to webpages in books

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In multiple multiplayer servers I play in (e.g. Hypixel), There are books with text in them, and when you click on the text it takes you to a website.

How do I replicate this?

[image: Hypixel Daily Reward Book with link]

Comment: We need this in real life.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `clickEvent` with `open_url`:

```
/give @s minecraft:written_book{pages:["[\"\",{\"text\":\"Arqade\",\"color\":\"gray\",\"underlined\":true,\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"open_url\",\"value\":\"https://gaming.stackexchange.com/\"}}]"],title:"foo",author:"bar"}
```

[image: book]

[image: url opened]

Answer (score 15):

A good online website for creating books is [minecraftjson.com](https://minecraftjson.com/), where you can create books, `tellraw` commands and other JSON texts for Minecraft.

If you create a book, you can simply add a new piece of text, and then set a `clickEvent` with `open_url`, then type in the url, and you're done.